# How do I make the JQuery UI dialog "close" button look like an 'X' icon?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The "close" button is appearing as the text "close," with no styling to make it look like what a user would expect to see for closing a dialog.

Isn't a graphical 'X' icon the default close button?

How do I style it to look right?

Here's my dialog initialization (if I leave out the "closeText" option then it defaults to "close" in the upper-left-hand corner of the dialog box):

```
$("#signInDialog").dialog({ dialogClass: "login",
                            zIndex: 20,
                            modal: true,
                            closeText: 'X'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default close icon in jQuery UI framework:

```
.ui-icon-close{background-position:-80px -128px}
```

or

```
.ui-icon-circle-close{background-position:-32px -192px}
```

Just take a look into generated CSS and make sure you downloaded the framework correctly (with all images).

Comment: That's it - I forgot to add the CSS and images to my project.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this value instead of 'X'.... the value is `&#215;`

use it similar to this... wherever you need...

```
<a id="some_id">&#215;</a>
```

might work...

Answer (score 0):

HTML provides a close icon,
an Unicode character for close is `&times;`.
you can use it similar to this...

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)'>&times;</a>
```